# the report viewer is not generating the report

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is the code that run on code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    string type = Request.QueryString["type"];
    string q =(string) Session["query"];
    string b=(string) Session["bg"];
    string r=(string) Session["rh"];
    string k=(string) Session["key"];

    if (type == "browse") {
        SqlConnection c= db.getConnection();
        c.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter x=new SqlDataAdapter(q,c);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        x.Fill(ds);
        ReportParameter[] parm = new ReportParameter[3];
        parm[0] = new ReportParameter("BT","");
        parm[1] = new ReportParameter("RH",r );
        parm[2] = new ReportParameter("KEY",k );
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @".\Reports\DonorsBrowse.rdlc" ;
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parm);
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1",ds.Tables[0]));
        ReportViewer1.DataBind();

        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
    }
}
```

This is the `aspx` page code

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    </div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
</form>
```

What am I missing? The report view loads but it is empty. 
it there missing options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it

just need to wrap all the code in

```
if(!IsPostBack){
//code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by doing the following things:

1. Write your code behind code inside `Page_init` method instead of `Page_Load`.

   ```
   Page_init(object sender, EventArgs e){
       if(!IsPostBack){
           // your code
       }
   }
   ```
2. Check your report viewer in the output window if it is showing error.
3. Check your report path.